# TinyMCE 1.3b8 links in Plone 4.3b1?

Tags: tinymce, plone

I'm finding myself unable to add links ("a" tags) via the version of Products.TinyMCE in Plone 4.3b1.  Switching to a non-visual editor and manually adding a link works fine, but using the chainlink icon in TinyMCE brings up an insert/edit popup window that doesn't appear to have anyplace to enter the destination address.  There's a "search" text field, but entering text into it does not enable the "OK" button.

Here's a screenshot of what I am seeing:
[image: screenshot]

Does anyone know if this is a known issue, or if I'm just completely missing how to enter links, or have any light to shed on this?  Thanks.

UPDATE:
The problem seems to be that the popup's tabs are not un-hideing the relevant divs.  When I use Firebug to switch div external_panel from class="hide" to class="show" the missing material appears; I also have to use Firebug to remove a disabled="disable" from the OK button in order to press it.  A screenshot showing the segments is below.  I've used the tgz file of the unified installer; is it possible that there is a variation between that installer's contents and the binary installer for the Mac?

The problem is showing up on a plain vanilla fresh install performed by

- - untarring the 4.3b1 unified installer tgz file,
- - running the command ./install.sh --target=/home/me/P4.3b1 from the installer's dir
- - going to /home/me/P4.3b1/zinstance
- - running the command bin/instance fg
- - going in the browser to localhost:8080,
- - creating a Plone instance and logging into it as admin
- - going immediately to edit the front page of the site.

Version overview from site setup page is as follows:Version Overview

- - Plone 4.3b1 (4302)
- - CMF 2.2.7
- - Zope 2.13.19
- - Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug 1 2012, 05:16:07) [GCC 4.6.3]
- - PIL 1.7.7 (Pillow)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hav you selected some text before clicking on the link icon?

Comment: Afraid I have, but thanks for the try. I've also gone in and added allowed classes to the control panel for TinyMCE, and tried switching between absolute and relative URLs via the control panel.

Comment: If this helps, another odd thing happens on my install; trying to save an edit (for example, of the site root), brings up a popup asking if I'm sure I want to leave the page.  Saying yes continues on through the save cycle with no problem

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to say cross browser compatibility issue. It looks like this in Firefox and works as expected:

[image]

Comment: Hmmm.  I pulled mine up in Firefox and it's still missing the body of the popup.  I've disabled all add-ons except for Plone JQuery Integration 1.7.2 and jQuery UI 1.9.2.0.

Comment: Tried disabling all but Plone JQuery Integration 1.7.2 and Plone JQuery Tools Integration 1.5.2, but the missing fields are still missing.  I'll try reinstalling from scratch and let folks know what happens.

Comment: I just went to Plone-4.3b1-UnifiedInstaller and ran "./install.sh --target=/home/me/P4.3b1 standalone."  Then went to /home/me/P4.3b1/zinstance and ran "bin/instance fg"  Then tried the edit view on the site's Welcome page, clicked on the "What's new in Plone" link, clicked on the chainlink icon, clicked on the external tab, and the body is still empty.  Here's the version overview as it appears on the site setup page: Version Overview
Plone 4.3b1 (4302)
CMF 2.2.7
Zope 2.13.19
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug 1 2012, 05:16:07) [GCC 4.6.3]
PIL 1.7.7 (Pillow)

Comment: Same issue in both Firefox and Chrome/Chromium, and I neglected in the prior comment to mention having clicked on the "Create a Plone Site" button and having saved the resulting form.  But I can't imagine how to get a more vanilla install.  Ubuntu 12.04.1, 32 bit, nothing special about the Ubuntu version.

Comment: Using firebug in Firefox, I can see that even when the External tab has been selected, the div with id="external_panel" is set to class="hide"; changing it in firebug to class="show" does make the External link and http:// spinner and the associated entry area show up (but at the bottom of the popup.  Screenshot: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/18212385/plone_tinymce.png